# How Do I Get the Overall.RMS_level in Real-Time from a UDP Stream as an Integer Appended to as Shared Log File?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, audio, ffmpeg

My goal is to monitor the audio of a UDP stream in real time to detect whether or not the audio is missing or too low in volume. Ultimately append to a log file that contains the integer values in decibels.
If only there was an output file specification **sharedfile** such as:

```
key=lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level:sharedfile=log.txt
```

If ffmpeg were to open the file as shared write or shared append then external scripts would have access to the output file as it is being written to.

I tried ffprobe and ffmpeg and the only valid output I could get is using ffmpeg.

ffmpeg gives the correct results however the output file specified as "log.txt" is open for output lock by ffmpeg and no data is written to it until you hit ctrl-c to stop the process at which time the output file is closed. I will write a script to poll the output file in real time as the file is being written to but only if I can figure out how to tell ffmpeg to append to "log.txt" for each sample taken.

Please advise on an alternate method or a fix to this method.

**Attempt 1 Using ffmpeg**

```
ffmpeg -i 'udp://@232.1.1.5:30120' -af astats=metadata=1:reset=1,ametadata=print:key=lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level:file=log.txt -f null -
```

File Sample of log.txt" contents after ctrl-c

```
frame:0    pts:0       pts_time:0
lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level=-34.210103
frame:1    pts:1536    pts_time:0.032
lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level=-31.515254
frame:2    pts:3072    pts_time:0.064
lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level=-32.894668
frame:3    pts:4609    pts_time:0.0960208
lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level=-33.187652
```

**Attempt 2 Using ffprobe**

```
ffprobe -i 'udp://@232.1.1.5:30120',astats=metadata=1:reset=1 -show_entries frame=pkt_pts_time:frame_tags=lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level,lavfi.astats.1.RMS_level,lavfi.astats.2.RMS_level -of csv=p=0
```

This works and displays the time code only. It displays blank lines in console output for lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS.  I'm think the problem has to do with lavfi?

Sample output to console:

```
22508.110500
22507.361267


22508.143867
22507.393267


22508.177244
22507.425267
```

I tried changing the command line to specify -f lavfi before the -i input but it returns an error:

```
ffprobe -f lavfi  -i 'udp://@232.1.1.5:30120',astats=metadata=1:reset=1 -show_entries frame=pkt_pts_time:frame_tags=lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level,lavfi.astats.1.RMS_level,lavfi.astats.2.RMS_level -of csv=p=0
```

Returns:

```
[lavfi @ 0x55c69784f840] No such filter: 'udp://'
udp://@232.1.1.5:30120,astats=metadata=1:reset=1: Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out a working example bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Run ffmpeg in the background
ffmpeg -nostats -i 'udp://@232.1.1.5:30120' -filter_complex ebur128=peak=true -f null -  >>audio_metadata.txt 2>&1 &
while true; do
  # Output to Screen
  cat audio_metadata.txt | tail -1 | tr -s ' ' | grep -oP '(?<=FTPK: )-?[0-9]+'
  # Output to File
  #cat audio_metadata.txt | tail -1 | tr -s ' ' | grep -oP '(?<=FTPK: )-?[0-9]+' > db_meter.txt
  sleep .3 # Adjust 100ms up or down for best sample rate without too many repeats
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I added an option on 10th Jan to allow the metadata filters to flush data immediately to disk. So, use attempt 1 as modified below after updating to a **current** git build

```
ffmpeg -i 'udp://@232.1.1.5:30120' -af astats=metadata=1:reset=1,ametadata=print:key=lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level:file=log.txt:direct=1 -f null -
```

Earlier, ffmpeg would flush data to a file protocol output when the buffer had at least 256kb in it. That's because the normal output traffic that ffmpeg deals in is relatively voluminous media payload, not a few dozen bytes of text.

Comment: What version number of ffmpeg do I update to for this feature?   I don't know how to compile from the source code.

Comment: For linux, get the *git master* build from https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS, will the above build work on Ubuntu?

Comment: There was a problem with ametadata here is the error message: 
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x5581c88e6100] Error initializing filter 'ametadata' with args 'print:key=lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level:file=log.txt:direct=1'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Option not found
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:1
Conversion failed!

Comment: You need a recent git master build.